# microsoft.quantum.development.kit qsc.dll error

Tags: q#

.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1809.701-preview\tools\qsc\qsc.dll'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
How to repair qsc.dll?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Explaining what you were doing when you got this message would be helpful. Also, some information about your environment would be great: it would be helpful to post the operating system you're using, whether you're using Visual Studio or VS Code, which version of either, which version of .NET Core you've installed, etc.

Comment: This error occurs on the first attempt to build during Writing a Quantum Program acccording to https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/quantum/quantum-WriteAQuantumProgram?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-vs2017

Comment: Used Windows 10 Education, version 1803, OS build 17134.345, 32-bit OS, x64-based processor, Visual Studio 2017 Community, .NET Core 2.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the quantum development kit only works with 64 bits OS (Windows, MacOS, Linux), and it appears that you are using a 32bit version of Windows.
I don't have any good option for you, except to upgrade the OS but I'm not certain there is a 64 bit version of Windows 10 Education.

As a limited option, you can try to execute some simple code in tio: https://tio.run/#qs-core.

I encourage you to create an item about this in https://quantum.uservoice.com/ where most of the feedback for the quantum development kit is gathered.

Comment: Everything works correctly with Windows 10 Education x64.